# "I'm loving" versus "I love"

Tags: tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I'm lovin' it”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/im-lovin-it)

> I love the car.
>   I'm loving the car.

It seems both of them are correct in strictly grammatical way, but the second one sounds a little bit weird. May any of you tell me how to deal with them?

Comment: Related: ["I'm lovin' it"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/im-lovin-it). Though I am not sure what exactly your question is. I have trouble parsing "Some of you may know how to call and to deal with them?" Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't know it was already there. By the way, I meant : "Some of you may know how to deal with it, and if you do and if there's a rule that makes it happen, how do we call it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right in saying they’re both grammatical. The present (‘I love’) is used normally to express a general and continuing state of affairs. The present progressive (‘I’m loving’), on the other hand, expresses something that is happening at the time of speaking. You’d expect a verb like ‘love’ to express something lasting for a little longer than the immediate present, but its use in the present progressive seems to have become more frequent. That may have something to do with the advertisements for McDonald’s ('I'm lovin' it'). It suggests an emotion in the here and now, but one which is not necessarily going to involve a lifetime’s commitment (although McDonald’s may actually hope otherwise).

Comment: Your anwsers are really helpful in anytime. Thank you again, Barrie :)

Comment: Kind of you to say so, and I hope it helps, but I’m afraid the use of English verb forms is a big subject, which cannot be adequately dealt with in a few lines.

Comment: One observation: I work with a lot of people of Indian origin, and they all seem to find this aspect (no pun intended) of English particularly difficult. I would speculate that Hindi does not draw a distinction between the present simple and the present continuous. I don't know Hindi, so can any native speakers confirm my speculation?

Comment: I am loving is not strictly correct grammatically in English- love is a stative verb. Logically I can make it work.